# mmenu iconbar at right side of page

Tags: mmenu

Does anyone know how to show the 'mmenu icon-bar' at the right side of the page in stead of the left?

```
body {
  overflow-x: hidden; }

.mm-page {
    background: inherit;
    min-height: 100vh;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-transform: translate(60px);
    transform: translate(60px);
    padding-right: 60px;
}

.mm-menu:first-child, .mm-menu.mm-current {
  display: block; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the padding from right to left and the translate from left to right:

```
.mm-page {
    -webkit-transform: translate(-60px);
    transform: translate(-60px);
    padding-left: 60px;
}
```